# insert into snowflake table from multiple values with arrays and objects

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to **insert multiple rows with arrays and structs**, via an SQL statement, into Snowflake.
To insert arrays of values into a column I am using the `ARRAY_CONSTUCT` function and to insert the structures/dictionaries/objects I am using the `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` function.

E.g.

```sql
insert into "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"
("ID", "TS", "TEXT", "DATEONLY", "ARRAY", "OBJ", "BOOL", "DOUBLE", "INT", "DEC_18_9")
values
('id1', '2020-11-26 14:01:27.868', '19', '2020-11-26',
  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(0, 1, 2), OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('this', 'is', 'my', 'object', 'query',
  OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('field1', 'one', 'field2', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('field2a', 'two')),
  'field3', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(3, 4, 5)), FALSE, 178482300.96318725, 9, 12345619.876543190),
('id2', '2020-11-26 14:01:27.868', '19', '2020-11-26',
  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(0, 1, 2), OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('this', 'is', 'my', 'object', 'query',
  OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('field1', 'one', 'field2', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('field2a', 'two')),
  'field3', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(3, 4, 5)), FALSE, 178482300.96318725, 9, 12345619.876543190)
;
```

This results in an exception:

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(0, 1, 2)] in VALUES clause

Inserting a single row using this syntax works:

```sql
insert into "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"
("ID", "TS", "TEXT", "DATEONLY", "ARRAY", "OBJ", "BOOL", "DOUBLE", "INT", "DEC_18_9")
select 'id1', '2020-11-26 14:01:27.868', '19', '2020-11-26',
  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(0, 1, 2), OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('this', 'is', 'my', 'object', 'query',
  OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('field1', 'one', 'field2', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('field2a', 'two')),
  'field3', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(3, 4, 5)), FALSE, 178482300.96318725, 9, 12345619.876543190
;
```

However, it is unclear if and how this can be used for inserting multiple rows.

The table definition is:

```sql
create or replace temporary table "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"
("ID" STRING NOT NULL, "TS" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, "TEXT" STRING,
  "DATEONLY" DATE, "ARRAY" ARRAY, "OBJ" OBJECT, "BOOL" BOOLEAN,
  "DOUBLE" DOUBLE, "INT" BIGINT, "DEC_18_9" NUMBER (18, 9)
);
```

**What is the correct way to do this?**
(Do I need to spill the data into a file and load from there or is there a direct way to do this?)

The only mention of this I found was in an ["answer" here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008AI1sHSAT/is-there-a-literal-syntax-for-arrays).

To clarify, I am inserting data into a temporary table, from which I merge into another table, since I could not find a way to merge data via an SQL statement from values (i.e. not from a table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via trial and error, I found this solution:

```sql
INSERT INTO "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"
SELECT $1, $2, $3, $4, PARSE_JSON($5), PARSE_JSON($6), $7, $8, $9, $10
from values
('id1', '2020-11-26 14:01:27.868', '19', '2020-11-26', '[0, 1, 2]',
  '{"this": "is", "my": "object",
    "query": {"field1": "one", "field2": ["field2a", "two"], "field3": [3, 4, 5]}}',
   FALSE, 178482300.96318725, 9, 12345619.876543190),
('id2', '2020-11-26 14:01:27.868', '19', '2020-11-26', '[0, 1, 2]',
  '{"this": "is", "my": "object",
    "query": {"field1": "one", "field2": ["field2a", "two"], "field3": [3, 4, 5]}}',
   FALSE, 178482300.96318725, 9, 12345619.876543190)
;
```

FYI, from a brief testing, Snowflake identifies `NaN`, `-inf` and `inf` within the JSON without the quotes around them as floating point values e.g. `{"my_field": NaN}`.

Answer (score 3):

VALUES does not support ARRAY_CONSTRUCT expression, this is why you get "Invalid expression" error:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values.html#syntax

> Most simple arithmetic expressions and string functions can be
> evaluated at compile time, but most other expressions cannot.

You may use SELECT + UNION ALL instead of VALUES:

```
insert into "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"
("ID", "TS", "TEXT", "DATEONLY", "ARRAY", "OBJ", "BOOL", "DOUBLE", "INT", "DEC_18_9")
SELECT 'id1', '2020-11-26 14:01:27.868', '19', '2020-11-26',
  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(0, 1, 2), OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('this', 'is', 'my', 'object', 'query',
  OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('field1', 'one', 'field2', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('field2a', 'two')),
  'field3', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(3, 4, 5)), FALSE, 178482300.96318725, 9, 12345619.876543190
UNION ALL  
SELECT 'id2', '2020-11-26 14:01:27.868', '19', '2020-11-26',
  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(0, 1, 2), OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('this', 'is', 'my', 'object', 'query',
  OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('field1', 'one', 'field2', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('field2a', 'two')),
  'field3', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(3, 4, 5)), FALSE, 178482300.96318725, 9, 12345619.876543190;
```